# Find directory where target is defined

Tags: cmake

Is there a way in cmake to find the source directory of the CMakeLists.txt file in which a target was defined?

Somethign like:

```
if (TARGET Foo)
    message("Library Foo was alread built in ${LOCATION_OF_FOOS_CMAKE}")
else()
    add_library(Foo ...)
endif()
```

**Edit:**
Unfortunately, my cmake scripts have to work on a default ubuntu 14.04 installation. So I'm limited to **cmake 2.8**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use target property [`SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOURCE_DIR.html) (added with [CMake 3.7](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/release/3.7.html)):

```
get_target_property(FOO_SOURCE_DIR Foo SOURCE_DIR)
```

For older versions of CMake you can overwrite e.g. `add_library()` and define your own `SOURCE_DIR` target property:

```
function(add_library _target)
    _add_library(${_target} ${ARGN})
    set_target_properties(${_target} PROPERTIES SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
endfunction(add_library)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately my cmake scripts have to be compatible with cmake 2.8 (ubuntu14.04)